# JavaScript createElement: for loop freezes; while loop does not. Why?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, ubuntu-12.04, createelement

This is a question out of sheer curiosity as it baffles me. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and I tried this on Firefox 19.0.2 and Chromium 25.0.1364.160. Look at the two following pieces of JavaScript code (These are excerpts of a larger piece of code):

```
var Div = document.createElement('div');
var limit = 5;

var i = 0;
while (i<limit){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', anImage);
    Div.appendChild(img);
    i++;
}
return Div;
```

and

```
var Div = document.createElement('div');
var limit = 5;

for (i=0; i<limit; i++){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', anImage);
    Div.appendChild(img);
}
return Div;
```

Now the 'while' loop works as expected while the 'for' loop freezes the browser. Why does it do that? Where is the difference?

I looked for a similar case on the Interwebs, but nothing stuck out as the perfect answer. Here are similar ones, but not quite the same.

[Appending elements to DOM in a loop structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198540/appending-elements-to-dom-in-a-loop-structure#)

[For Loop Freezes Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399340/for-loop-freezes-javascript#)

Actually, the second one gave me the idea to try a while loop in the first place, but it is never explained, why it makes a difference...

Thanks for any clarification :)

Comment: Can you post the full code in jsfiddle or something? where is `anImage` defined?

Comment: Apparently missing the `var` in `for (var i=0;` but it shouldn't make much of a difference from your given code (unless in strict mode). Can you reproduce the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: You could add `console.log(i)` inside the loop to find out what's going on, but given the above code I see no reason why it should freeze at all.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comments. I found the answer and it was an interesting conincidence. I forgot the 'var' in front of the i, i.e. creating a global variable, right? However, it was a for loop in a for loop (I didn't see it, because I moved it to a different function). So there must have been some counting issue of sorts. Localizing using var i solved that particular issue. I guess @Fabricio Matte gave me the hint that I needed to solve that particular riddle, So thanks buddy :)

Comment: And with regard to "Jack, Trott, Mr_Green, Jueecy and jAndy": I guess, it is not "that" localized :D The take home message here, kids. Don't create the same global variable for a nested for loop :P